What is the connection between bilinear and quadratic forms.
I know that a bilinear form $B$ on the $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathbb R^n$ is defined to be a map $B:\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n\to  \mathbb R$ which is linear in each coordinate.We know that a bilinear form is specified entirely by $B(e_i,e_j)$ i.e. $n^2$ many values where $n$ is the dimension of $V$.So we can have a matrix $M=(B(e_i,e_j)_{i, j})$ of $n\times n$ size,which gives complete information about  the bilinear form $B$.
On the other hand a quadratic form $Q$ is a quadratic polynomial function from $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ which takes in an element $\mathbf x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}$ from $\mathbb R^2$ and spits out an expression $Q(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}x_ix_j=\sum_i a_ii^2+\sum\sum_{i\neq j}a_{ij}x_ix_j$ and it can be given in matrix form via $A=((a_{ij})_{i,j})_{n\times n}$.
If we restrict ourselves to symmetric forms then $B$ is a symmetric bilinear form iff $B(e_i,e_j)=B(e_j,e_i)$ for all $i,j=1,2,...,n$ i.e. iff $M$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with $\mathbb R$-entiries.
And for quadratic forms $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ for all $i,j$ ,which gives $Q$ as simpler form $Q(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_i a_{ii}x_i^2+\sum\sum_{i<j} 2a_{ij}x_ix_j$ simpler matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ which is symmetric.
As far as I remember from my Bachelors' course on Mathematics,there is a one-one correspondence between the $\mathbb R$-bilinear forms on $\mathbb R^n$ and quadratic forms on $\mathbb R^n$,because characteristics of the base field $\mathbb R$ is $\chi(\mathbb R)\neq 2$.Thus we can build the correspondence between them as follows:
$B$ Symmetric Bilinear Form on $\mathbb R^n$ given by the matrix $M$ is such that $B(\mathbf{x,y})=\mathbf x^tM\mathbf y$ and in that case define the corresponding symmetric quadratic form as $Q(\mathbf x)=\mathbf x^t M\mathbf x$ and conversely for a symmetric quadratic form $Q$ with matrix $A$(which looks like $Q(\mathbf x)=\mathbf x^tA\mathbf x$),define the Bilinear form $B$ corresponding to $Q$ by $B(\mathbf{x,y})=\mathbf x^t A\mathbf y$.
This correspondence is a bijective correspondence.Hence an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix may represent both a bilinear form $B(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)=x^t A \mathbf y$ and the quadratic form $Q)\mathbf x)=\mathbf x^t A \mathbf x$.
Am I right in whatever I have said here?

I have seen $\chi$ used for Euler characteristic. Is it also used for characteristic of a field?

@coiso it is just a notation used by me.....is it that important for our present discussion?

What you say seems entirely correct (except for the fact that functions do not spit).
However, to understand the relation between different kinds of forms, one obscures matters by limiting oneself to the very special vector spaces$~\Bbb R^n$. The fact that you talk about the characteristic of the base field (which is not really an issue when considering only those spaces) suggests you have some interest in generality, so I'll use a modest amount of that.
If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a field$~K$, bilinear forms on $V$ are defined just like you did as functions of two arguments $V\times{V}\to{K}$ the become liner functions $V\to{K}$ whenever one of the arguments is fixed to any particular vector. Quadratic forms on the other hand are functions $V\to{K}$ that lie in the subspace of all such functions spanned by the products $\alpha\beta:v\mapsto\alpha(v)\beta(v)$ of two linear functions $\alpha,\beta:V\to{K}$.
There is a natural map from bilinear forms to quadratic forms: if $B$ is a bilinear form, then $Q:v\mapsto{B(v,v)}$ is a quadratic form. To see that $Q$ is in the span of the products of two linear forms, fix any (ordered) basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ of $V$, with coordinate functions $\alpha_i$, so that $v=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i(v)e_i$ for every $v\in{V}$, then by bilinearity $B(v,v)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nB(e_i,e_j)\alpha_i(v)\alpha_j(v)$ for all$~v\in{V}$, so that
$Q=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nB(e_i,e_j)\alpha_i\alpha_j$. This map is surjective but not injective (unless $n\leq1$): its kernel is formed by subspace the alternating bilinear forms (by definition of the latter) which has dimension $\binom{n}2$ (a basis is formed by the family of forms $(v,w)\mapsto\alpha_i(v)\alpha_j(w)-\alpha_j(v)\alpha_i(w)$ for the pairs $(i,j)$ with $i<j$).
A map in the opposite direction can be given only it the characteristic of $K$ is not$~2$. Assuming that, the space of bilinear forms is the direct sum of the subspaces of symmetric bilinear forms and that of alternating bilinear forms (which in this case are also call anti-symmetric bilinear forms). If $B$ is symmetric, we can recover in this case $B$ from the associated quadratic form $Q$ by a so called polarisation formula: one can either use $B(v,w)=\frac12(Q(v+w)-Q(v)-Q(w))$ or $B(v,w)=\frac14(Q(v+w)-Q(v-w))$. In both cases, it is easy to show that this is indeed the original form $B$ (using its bilinearity and symmetry). We therefore get a linear (polarisation) map from quadratic forms to symmetric bilinear forms that is the inverse of the restriction of the initial (forward) map to symmetric bilinear forms. Thus we have explicit and mutually inverse linear bijections between these two spaces of forms.
In the case of characteristic$~2$, the above description goes wrong in several ways. Now the alternating bilinear forms are in fact a subspace of the space of symmetric bilinear forms, so (if $n>1$) there is no hope of recovering a symmetric bilinear form $B$ from the associated quadratic form$~Q$ (and obviously both polarisation formulas are meaningless). Lacking a direct sum decomposition of the space of bilinear forms in this case, we can only describe the space of quadratic forms as in bijection with the quotient of the space of all bilinear forms by its subspace of alternating bilinear forms.

@MarcvanLeewen Thank you!This is more than a complete answer!Contains a lot of general insight which I would be missing otherwise.

Yes, except there is no "symmetric" quadratic form. If $Q(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is a function of $n$ coordinates which comprise a single vector $x$, saying "$Q(x_i,x_j)=Q(x_j,x_i)$ for all $i,j$" is meaningless.
Any matrix $A$ may be decomposed as $A=A_0+A_1$, with a symmetric part $A_0$ and an antisymmetric part $A_1$. Since the transpose is $A^T=\cdots=A_0-A_1$, we can solve and say $A_0=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ is the "symmetrization" and $A_1=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)$ is the "antisymmetrization."
Then any bilinear form $B(x,y)=x^TAy$ becomes $B_0(x,y)+B_1(x,y)$, where $B_0(x,y)=x^TA_0y$ is a symmetric bilinear form and $B_1(x,y)=x^TA_1y$ is an antisymmetric bilinear form. (The coordinate-free formulas are $B_0(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(B(x,y)+B(y,x))$ and $B_1(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(B(x,y)-B(y,x))$. Symmetric means $B_0(y,x)=B_0(x,y)$ and antisymmetric means $B_1(y,x)=-B_1(x,y)$.
Given any bilinear form $B$, there is a corresponding quadratic form $Q(x):=B(x,x)$. Observe that if $B$ is antisymmetric, then $Q(x)=0$ identically, so $Q(x)$ only depends on the symmetric part of $B$, not the antisymmetric part. That is, $Q(x)=B(x,x)=x^TAx=x^TA_0x$.
To understand a little better, play with the $2\times2$ case a bit. Notice how, when using a matrix $[\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix}]$ to create a quadratic form, only the sum $b+c$ matters, so without loss of generality we can choose $b=c$ (i.e. it is symmetric). And when $a,d=0$ and $b=-c$, the resulting $Q$ is $0$.
Conversely, if $B$ is symmetric, then it satisfies the polarization identity $$Q(x+y)=Q(x)+2B(x,y)+Q(y),$$ which outside of characteristic $2$ allows us to solve for $B$ in terms of $Q$. Thus, there is a bijection between quadratic forms and symmetric bilinear forms (really, a vector space isomorphism).

I think you have a $Q(x, x)$ where you mean $Q(x)$. Good answer though! Tangential comment: characteristic 2 is a nightmare for bilinear and other more general forms (sesquilinear forms) as I have come to find out recently. Pretty much nothing nice works there!

@coiso Yes,you are right!I was being a less mindful at the time of writing this,thank you for the correction.The answer is very enlightening too!
